# Vim jump last mark-different file

Tags: vim

:bn , :bp just switches buffers

I want something like ctrl-o, which has a 'stack' of marks it jumps through.

However, I want it to ignore marks in the same file ... i.e
i want ctrl-my-o to be ctrl-o until you hit a different file
and ctrl-my-i to be ctrl-i until you hit a different file

Is there somethig like this in vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, that i know of, but you do have the argument list which will let you put some files in an list and then you can go through them with :n and :N (:h :ar).

If you want something to help you switch buffers (and files and directory etc...), use FuzzyFinder.